# Is it safe to use JMX to extract metadata from Gemfire?

Tags: jmx, gemfire

I have a requirement to extract metadata(Member and Region attributes) from Pivotal Gemfire. Is it safe to connect to JMX Manager node to extract the metadata using mBeans? Is there an alternative to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is perfectly safe to do so. In fact, several internal tools (like [PULSE](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/tools_modules/pulse/pulse-overview.html)) use JMX to access the information about members, regions, metrics, etc.
Another option would be to use the [gfsh describe member](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/describe.html#topic_D62F3D42B1D84CF68F03D54D5122806A) and [gfsh describe region](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/describe.html#topic_DECF7D3D33F54071B6B8AD4EA7E3F90B) commands.
Hope this helps, cheers.